# C#: Drawing only a portion of a path

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have a series of points in a GraphicsPath; for our purpose lets assume its the outline of an uppercase B.  I want to be able to be able to draw only the bottom portion that would resemble an uppercase L.

I'd like to be able to select a window of points from the GraphicsPath. Is there a handy way to do this without doing point interpolation; ie have to write code to calculate slope math and possibly derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that there's a way to actually tell the `Graphics` class to "stop" halfway through a path, or somehow create a new path that intersects with a bounding box (without implementing the method yourself), but if you're just doing this so you can draw a certain part of the path, then you should be able to achieve what you want by setting the clipping region.

See the [Graphics.ClipBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clipbounds.aspx) property, which takes a `RectangleF`, or [Graphics.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip.aspx), which is a `Region` (the former is generally easier to use, unless you already have a `Region` instance).

If you need to use the partial path for something else then I'm not aware of any built-in way to do it.